# Linux adding wordlist for spell checking

Tags: aspell

We have a small linux cluster (12 machines). Before we populate our database (then create a report from database contents) we would like to spell check a few files. The problem I have is some fields in the text file will contain lists of drugs and other medical terms and other acronyms that the spell checker will automatically think is a spelling error. Eg the line

`DRUGS:=ASPIRIN;BISOPROLOL;RAMIPRIL;GTN;TAMSULOSIN;PIZOTIFEN;CO-CODAMOL`

When I issue the command
`aspell --lang en_GB check filename`

It doesn't recognise most of these drugs?

Is it possible to create a wordlist (i.e a text file containing a list of accepted drugs and acronyms) that aspell can use so that:
(a) it ignores incorrectly spelled drugs
(b) If a drug is mis-spelled it suggests the correctly spelled version

Comment: Check the [manual](http://aspell.net/man-html/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can add a personal wordlist with the `--personal=FILE` or `-p` parameter:

```
aspell -p /path/to/my/wordlist check /path/to/the/file/to/check
```

Your personal wordlist should have one word per line.

If you do not want to type the option each time, you can add it to your `~/.aspell.conf` or `/etc/aspell.conf`.