# How can I export my aspell dictionary?

Tags: aspell, dictionary

At the moment, I'm working on a big LaTeX document about mathematics and once in a while I do some spell-checking on it. As you can guess, there are a lot of words which are not in a standard dictionary. But I've added them with `aspell` with <kbd>a</kbd> to the standard dictionary.

```
aspell -d de -t -c my-document.tex
```

Is there a way to export my words (and only those)?

Restoring seems to be quite simple: [another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/103644/4784).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When dealing with `aspell` if you're not sure where things are stored it's best to consult its configuration to find out.

```
$ aspell --lang=en dump config | less
```

The 2 items that will tell you where the added words are ending up are as follows:

```
# home-dir (string)
#   location for personal files
# default: <$HOME|./> = /home/saml

# personal (string)
#   personal dictionary file name
# default: .aspell.<lang>.pws = .aspell.en.pws
```

So with this information in hand you can consult the file `$HOME/.aspell.en.pws`. Which contains the added words.

#### Example

Now say we have this file.

```
$ cat sample.txt 
smurf
loook
```

Now we spell check the file, `sample.txt`.

```
$ aspell -t -c sample.txt
```

[image: ss #1]

So we add the word `loook`, in the same manner you've described, using <kbd>a</kbd> with the word selected.

Now if we consult the file mentioned above.

```
$ cat .aspell.en.pws 
personal_ws-1.1 en 1 
loook
```

#### References

- [5.7 Format of the Personal and Replacement Dictionaries](http://aspell.net/man-html/Format-of-the-Personal-and-Replacement-Dictionaries.html)
- [Re: [Aspell-user] Where is the personal dictionary for English language?](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/aspell-user/2011-09/msg00022.html)
- [Creating your own personal aspell dictionary](http://blog.samat.org/2008/11/02/creating-your-own-personal-aspell-dictionary)

Answer (score 5):

There is a file where all the added entries are, which is by default (for english):

```
/home/user/.aspell.en.pws
```

http://aspell.net/man-html/Format-of-the-Personal-and-Replacement-Dictionaries.html